# Codesynthesis tag referring to a company?

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, tags

It was just [brought to my attention](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7781941/canonical-relation-operators#comment21279044_7781941) that [somebody introduced a tag excerpt in April 2012](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/9981909/2) narrowing the tag [codesynthesis](/questions/tagged/codesynthesis) to a company of that name. It would appear that most questions on that tag are asking something related to that company, while my own question is an instance of a counter example.

However, I know the term code synthesis to describe a wider methodology related to (or perhaps even synonymous in some situations) code generation. So, what should the tag be used for?

As far as I can tell, most questions ask about [xsd](/questions/tagged/xsd), which seems to be related to that company, so it seems redundant to use two tags for the same thing (and inconsistently so).

Comment: Ideally the tag should be product specific rather than the company name specific. Since the product in question is [codesynthesis xsd](http://www.codesynthesis.com/products/xsd/), and all tagged questions are related to that, the tag name and description should be changed to reflect this.

Comment: Yes, a product tag is better. Another thing: earlier today I removed the tag `codesynthesis` from 3 questions that were not related to the company Codesynthesis.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8086595/how-are-object-pointers-in-objective-c-synthesized  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6985706/convert-a-method-name-to-bean-name-at-runtime  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1317780/how-to-use-svn-to-make-our-code-in-sync     About the usage of the tag `codesynthesis` in the more abstract meaning of the word: Maybe the already existing tag `code-generation` could be used for that?